# Django REST EmailAddress matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

I am using django `rest-auth` and `allauth` to authenticate users. After successful signup and email verification, I implemented a login view which subclasses `rest-auth.views.LoginView` like below:

```
class ThLoginView(LoginView):

    def get(self, request):
        form = CustomUserLoginForm()
        return render(request, "users/login.html", context={"form": form})
```

with my own form:

```
class CustomUserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
  
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

The problem is that when I login I get this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /users/login/
EmailAddress matching query does not exist.
```

Another important thing that I have changed is that I am using email as the signup/login rather than the username:

### Settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

and my `user` model overwrites `AbstractBaseUser` like so:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The error seems to suggest that the search algorithm is not looking in the right place for the emails. The user's email is definitely entered since I can oversee this in the admin page. why is this error occurring?

Note: this error also occurs if I use the REST browseable API so it is not linked to my form and template.

### Full traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_auth',
 'rest_auth.registration',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py" in dispatch
  49.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py" in post
  103.         self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
  235.                 self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in run_validation
  433.             value = self.validate(value)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/serializers.py" in validate
  108.                 email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ba/venv/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  408.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /users/login/
Exception Value: EmailAddress matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Please show your full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added full traceback

Comment: This doesn't seem to be using your LoginView at all. Are you sure you have configured the URLs correctly?

Comment: `/users/login/` is using `ThLoginView` which is subclassing `LoginView` : `path('login/', views.ThLoginView.as_view(), name='rest_logout'),`

Comment: I can't understand what you are doing here. rest_auth does not use forms, it uses serializers, and you haven't customised what serializer it will use. And what is your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman AUTH_USER_MODEL is my custom user class that is subclassing AbstractBaseUser. I am using a form to display it in a template. should I replace the form with a serializer or add a `serializer_class` attribute?

Answer (score 5):

You get this error because the email address you are using to login does not exist in the database table Account Email address. `Dj-rest-auth` or `Django-rest-auth` packages creates a table for Email address to track verified users.

You may run into this error when you try to login with users that are created from `manage.py` commands such as `manage.py createsuperuser`. Basically, the users created from either django admin console or management command will not create an entry in the Email address table.

To fix this error you may have to create a new entry under `Accounts> Email Addresses` from admin console or delete the user from `Authentication and authorization> Users` in admin console and register again using django-rest-auth API endpoint(which will automatically add this entry in Email Address table).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem when I worked on my custom user model. The reason was that I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` at the console with the default django user model first. Later, I implemented my custom user model and did the migrations.
Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) describes the challenge in detail:

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and many-to-many relationships, for example.
>
> This change can’t be done automatically and requires manually fixing your schema, moving your data from the old user table, and possibly manually reapplying some migrations. See #25313 for an outline of the steps.

I would suggest to start with a new database, if you can. This is how i solved that issue. Otherwise try to follow this [tutorial](https://ruddra.com/posts/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project/) or this [tutorial](https://rasulkireev.com/custom-user-model-mid-project-django/)

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem, it is probable you read token the bad way. for my case i used username user id , get the value with email.

So do it like that

```
payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms='HS256')
user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope u can fix the issue by creating a user in email address model providing the user id, email and setting verified and primary boolean fields  to true; it was solved the issue for me